# Calculate the time complexity of a reccurence relation, Big-Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

I'm trying to find the Big-Oh of this recurrence relation:
T(N) = 4T(N/2) + N^2.

T(1) = 1

Comment: Great recurrence relation, what is your question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem trying to find the complexity in big-O notation

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: my answer turned out to be O(N^2)

Comment: It looks like [O(N^2 log N)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(N)+%3D+4T(N%2F2)+%2B+N%5E2,+T(1)+%3D+1) to me.

Comment: Can you show me the steps of doing it @PaulR

Comment: Click on the link in my comment above.

Comment: Look up the master theorem. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

From the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) we can say T(n) = \Theta(N^2 log(N)) (see case 2).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the recurrence relation is :
 [O(N^2 log N)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(N)%20%3D%204T(N%2F2)%20%2B%20N%5E2,%20T(1)%20%3D%201)